# left join where field exist or is null

Tags: sql, join, null, left-join

I need do a left join of 2 tables: debits and payments. I have 2 limit date fields in debits (date from and data until). I need to join ALL the rows from debits for a period to all the rows from payments but contraint to the limit fields.

My query is:

```
Select * from Debits a left join Payments b on a.client=b.client
where b.payments_date>=date_from and b.payments<=date_until
```

The problem is that I get an inner, an I still need a left join.

How can I solve this? Is it a way to say if the client exists in the payment table restrict it to the fields limits, and if not bring it with no payment???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the filter from the where clause to the join.  In this case, all you have to do is change the word "where" to "and" and Bob will be your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

you are close, have a condition like this

```
Select *, isNULL(b.payments, 'No Payment') 
from Debits a 
left join Payments b 
on a.client=b.client
on b.payments_date>=date_from 
and b.payments>=date_until
```